# Android Studio Intent Not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i am trying to start a new activity when a user click a imageView...
the imageView is on CardView.
I have added the Intent to the .java but still the app crashes..
here is my code

```
    package com.example.rishav.thisiscarsearch20;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MarutiSuzukiScrollingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_maruti_suzuki_scrolling);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        }
    public void onBaleno (View view){
        Intent baleno = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(baleno);
    }



}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/onmarutiselectcars"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.rishav.thisiscarsearch20.MarutiSuzukiScrollingActivity">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView12"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:text="Maruti Baleno"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/baleno01"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/balenointro"
                    android:onClick="onBaleno" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview01"
                    android:layout_width="273dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:text="Price :  5.3 - 8.7 Lakh"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />


            </LinearLayout>



        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

when i run this on emulator i get the following error

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.rishav.thisiscarsearch20, PID: 2407
>                     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method please(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView with id 'baleno01'
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: `Could not find method please(View) in a parent`... Where is that?

Comment: add line 
    ImageView baleno01 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.baleno01);

in onCreate();

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onBaleno (View view){
    Intent baleno = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(baleno);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

bro i was also getting the same problem, so i made another activity and used the intent to visit the new activity and it works for that one so i just copies the content to new activity and i notice while coping from the old activity that import (toolbar) was showing not being used so i didn't copied that and content related to that and it is working..

Comment: Please put some effort to write understandable answers. E.g. use dots to separate your sentences. This isn't an SMS or a chat message.